# How to create a "relative time" variable from date?

Tags: r, date, time, dplyr

I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(country = c("US", "US", "US", "UK", "UK", "UK", 
"UK"), date = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04", 
"2020-01-05", "2020-01-06", "2020-01-07"), y = 1:7, treatment = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L
))
```

Here is the df:

```
  country date       y treatment
  US      2020-01-01 1    0
  US      2020-01-02 2    1
  US      2020-01-03 3    0
  UK      2020-01-01 4    0
  UK      2020-01-02 5    0
  UK      2020-01-03 6    1
  UK      2020-01-04 7    0
```

I need to create varible which will reflect relative time before and after treatment with zero for the date of treatment. So, in this case it should be equal to

```
relative_time = c(-1,0,1,-2,-1,0,1)
```

How can I create such a varible for each group of country?

Comment: The code for df is not the same as the data frame displayed. Please fix the question.

Comment: Exactly. If the country is missing, this is not possible. You need the country group.

Comment: Sorry, took the freedom to edit the post and make the reproducible example right.

Comment: One addition. This example implicitly assumes that there is only one treatment per country. Readers might wanna know that when adapting from this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also `dplyr`, bit shorter

```
library(lubridate)

df %>%
    mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
    group_by(country) %>%
    mutate(time_to_treatment = date - date[treatment == 1])
```

outputs

```
  country date           y treatment time_to_treatment
  <chr>   <date>     <int>     <dbl> <drtn>           
1 US      2020-01-01     1         0 -1 days          
2 US      2020-01-02     2         1  0 days          
3 US      2020-01-03     3         0  1 days          
4 UK      2020-01-04     4         0 -2 days          
5 UK      2020-01-05     5         0 -1 days          
6 UK      2020-01-06     6         1  0 days          
7 UK      2020-01-07     7         0  1 days
```

Comment: `lubridate` needs to be loaded in order to use the function  `ymd`

Comment: true. Will add it.

Answer (score -1):

The provided data is different from the displayed data, so the displayed data was used.

```
require(tidyverse)

df = read.table( text = 'country date       y treatment
                US      2020-01-01 1    0
                US      2020-01-02 2    1
                US      2020-01-03 3    0
                UK      2020-01-01 4    0
                UK      2020-01-02 5    0
                UK      2020-01-03 6    1
                UK      2020-01-04 7    0', header  = T) 

df <- 
df %>% group_by(country) %>% 
  mutate(rank_row = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(treatment_row_number = if_else(treatment == 1, rank_row, 0L)) %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  mutate(treatment_row_number = max(treatment_row_number)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(relative_time = rank_row - treatment_row_number) %>% 
  select(-rank_row, -treatment_row_number) 
 
df


# A tibble: 7 x 5
  country date           y treatment relative_time
  <fct>   <fct>      <int>     <int>         <int>
1 US      2020-01-01     1         0            -1
2 US      2020-01-02     2         1             0
3 US      2020-01-03     3         0             1
4 UK      2020-01-01     4         0            -2
5 UK      2020-01-02     5         0            -1
6 UK      2020-01-03     6         1             0
7 UK      2020-01-04     7         0             1
```

Comment: Um, this is not reliable the dataframe **must** be sorted correctly in advance, otherwise you will get something wrong. And if you don't convert the `date` column into a `date` you cannot even sort by it. You might wann fix this in your answer.